# Tomcat authentication asks to relogin even though browser has not been closed

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

I'm using DIGEST authentication in my web app running under Tomcat. 
I noticed that after every so often it asks me to re-login: the pop-up window asking me for username and password shows up again. 
How do I prevent this behavior ? I only want to login the first time I open the website.

I notice this happens after several refresh on the web browser. If no refresh, then it won't ask me for the username and password again. I thought the default behavior won't ask me for authentication again as long as I don't close my browser. Is my understanding correct ?

I'm not sure whether it helps or not but I have tried to set the session-timeout to -1 in my web.xml file but it doesn't seem to help.

```
<session-config>  
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>  
</session-config>
```

---

Here's the complete web.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee    
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">  

<resource-env-ref>
    <description>user db</description>
    <resource-env-ref-name>UserDatabase</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>


<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>user-resource</web-resource-name>
        <description>pages which require login</description>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>Must authenticate before querying the system</description>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>      
    </auth-constraint>


    <user-data-constraint>
          <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>       
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
</login-config>  

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Has the server been restarted? That can clear session data, it depends on your server configuration.

Comment: Yes, You need to restart after web.xml change

Comment: I did the restart but I still have same problem.

Comment: I'm assuming you have defined security constraints in your web.xml - can you post your full web.xml?

Comment: I just added web.xml in my posting

Comment: I tested using Apache JMeter with Loop count equals to 100 because I thought every iteration will be similar like a refresh situation in the browser. I always get HTTP 200 ok response.